# Vim: Open new explorer tab with the directory of the file you're currently on

Tags: vim, keymapping

I'd like to open a new tab with the file explorer set to the directory of the file I have open, instead of the directory I opened vim from. For example,

If I do:

```
~: cd ~/dir1
~/dir1: vim dir2/dir3/dir4/file1
```

Then from inside that window I would like to open a new tab with a file explorer currently showing the contents of `~/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/` (the directory of the file in the currently active tab).

I have the following mapping set up:

```
nnoremap <leader>t :tabnew<CR>:Ex . <CR>
```

But that just opens the file explorer at `~/dir1`. How can I edit this key-mapping to pass to `:Ex` the directory of the file that is currently open?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
:tabe %:h
```

Opens a tab, editing the 'head of current file-name' (`%` is the name of the current file, `:` adds modifiers, and `h` is the basename/head modifier), that is the directory.

Comment: This is wonderful... I love learning something new about VIM :]

Answer (score 76):

Alternatively to `:tabe %:h`, there is also

`:Texplore`

or simply `:Te`

Comment: For me this doesn't open up the tab in the directory of the file that is currently open. In other words, using my example above this will open a tab and file explorer pointing to `~/dir1`

Comment: Diego: you're right, :Te is in this regard inconsistent with all the other :Explore commands. This looks like a bug, and I have reported it. Sorry for the very late answer :D

Comment: update: it looks like the bug has been fixed as of vim 7.4.827

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.
:Te - such and elegant command.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to François 's answer, you can also open new split window, in case you want to do comparison side by side horizontally or vertically by using `:Hexplore` or `:Vexplore` respectively.